# How to prevent build failure with custom Maven Plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

How do i prevent my custom maven plugin to fail the build?

I do not want to the build to fail if there is an issue in the custom maven plugin. How do i implement that?

Any examples would be helpful.

I see  but not sure how to configure that.

Comment: If you want, you can catch all exceptions in the `execute` method and discard them. But is it really sensible to ignore everything that went wrong in your plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believing https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-plugin-api/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/Mojo.html#execute(), I would "simply" catch *all* exceptions. (In mojo.execute())

Advanced: Introduce a plugin parameter à la `failOnError`(/+`failOnWarning`) ...and catch/throw accordingly.

Comment: Got it. Thank You.

Comment: Please use up-to-date information https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-plugin-api/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/Mojo.html#execute(). (Maven 2.2.1 is long end of life)...

Comment: ah, tyvm, @khmarbaise  ... that's what google "offered first" ..updated! (and sort of "current" urls would be cool for maven (..SEO and as "improvement proposal"))